# jQuery move element vertically with mousemove and Select text on mouseover

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, position, mouseover, mousemove

I am trying to do exactly what this webpage is using with share lyrics image(button).

http://www.metrolyrics.com/just-give-me-a-reason-lyrics-pink.html

**2 things are happening here I want**:

1. There is some lines' text is selected and saved inside some variable
   for further use.
2. The share lyrics image moving with mouse vertically.

I know this is something with jQuery, but I'm a novice of jQuery.

Done all my research but I was not able to find proper match that suits my need.
I read docs at jQueryUI(http://jqueryui.com/position/) as well but not getting what I want.

Can somebody help me with this please?

**HELP**
This is a little code I'm trying to use but the hover function doesn't seem to be working.

```
function appendText()

{

var txt1="Text.";              // Create text with HTML

var txt2=$("").text("Text.");  // Create text with jQuery

$("body").append(txt1,txt2);        // Append new elements

}

$('.line').hover(function(){

   $('.line').removeClass('hover');

   $(this).addClass('hover');

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its very simple:

on that website ever row is a `div` when on hover it lets jquery insert an `hover` class into that div `$().addClass('hover');` (and the folowing 3 divs). and in css it says that the `div` with a `hover` class `div.hover` has another background.

code that could have been used:

```
$('.line').hover(function(){
   $('.line').removeClass('hover');
   $(this).addClass('hover').next().addClass('hover').next().addClass('hover').next().addClass('hover');
});
```

css:

```
.line.hover {
background-color: #3333FF; //some colllor
}
```

to get the selected text:

```
 $('.hover').text()
```

or

```
$('.hover').each(function(){ 
$(this).text();
}
```

move the image to first selected div:

```
$('.line').hover(function(){
   $('.line').removeClass('hover');
   $("#share-image").appendTo(this);
.appendTo("#destination");$(this).addClass('hover').next().addClass('hover').next().addClass('hover').next().addClass('hover');
});
```

Comment: I would suggest you to read my question again please.
I'm not asking to change the color of background of hovered text.
I'm asking to move the share lyrics button vertically, like in that page and to select the text the background color is changed of and save it inside some variable.
Please correct me if I'm missing something.
Thanks

Comment: you asked how to get this done, i did show you how they did it, you could alter it you shouldnt let someone else write your jquery if you dont understand it yourself..

Comment: Thanks Joel,
I know I don;t have much knowledge of jQuery but was just trying to do it.
And thanks for the advise as well.

One more thing: 
`.appendTo("#destination");` 

 what would this be doing?

Comment: it replaces the dom element and adds/appends it to the destination dom element

Comment: This is code I'm trying to use. But the hover function does'nt seem to be working.
Am I missing something?

Comment: $('.line') is the selector, you might have used a wrong selector?

Comment: I'm using $('.line')  only.   :(

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code, might help the second question
[http://jsfiddle.net/bPfgT](http://jsfiddle.net/bPfgT/2/)

```
$('#menu').mousemove(function(my) {   
    var y = my.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    $('#follow').css({        
        'left': 0,
        'top': '' + y + 'px' 
    });
});
```